# How can I use java sockets to communicate between different networks?

Tags: java, sockets, security, port, router

I have java programs for my client and server, and they work fine within the same wifi network. But I need the clients to be able to connect to the server from the open internet. In questions like these

[How to connect client and server with the help of ip address which are connected to internet through different wifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371694/how-to-connect-client-and-server-with-the-help-of-ip-address-which-are-connected)

https://coderanch.com/t/667020/java/Socket-connections-networks

the solution is to manually reroute a port to the server from the router, making it open to connections from the outside. Is there a way to do this with just software on the server? I don't understand why manually dedicating ports is necessary since of course other applications on my computer (like games) that I install communicate with their servers back and forth without me having to manually go in and flip switches.

How can I achieve this with just software running on my server?

If there isn't another way, how do other applications communicate openly without manual router changes, and will opening up ports through my router result in security issues?

Comment: What port does your server listen on? Does your server have a static public IP address?

Comment: The typical pattern is that the client starts a connection by reaching out to the server; the server listens and waits for new client connections. Once a socket connection is established, either end (server or client) can write to or read from the socket. If you instead want the _server_ (remote) to be able to initiate a socket connection with the _client_ – and your client has a firewall in front of it – then you must permanently open a port on the firewall, thus giving the remote server some way to reach into the network to initiate a socket connection to the client.

Comment: As an analogy, you can unlock and open a locked door to your home (from the inside) whenever you want. Once it is open, you can interact with whoever is at the door. But it isn't possible for anyone else to just walk up and open your locked front door from the outside.

Comment: OH ok thanks so much! I'm pretty new to java networking so I thought that we were required to have a socket for each direction information was travelling. I didn't realize that one socket can go both ways. I will research that!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to double check this point; so if I manually open the port to the server on the router, will it cause any security concerns as long as I keep the program on the port securely password protected/properly encrypted? Even when the program is not running and there won't be any response to connection requests from the program at all? Let me know if I need to make this a separate question somewhere else.

Comment: If you open a port on your router, it is always a security concern. The best practice would be: don't do that, and instead always initiate the connection from the client computer that is already inside the firewall.

Comment: Ok. how do I get the server at a reachable place where clients that are inside firewalls can reach it from different networks then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change the architecture of your application. Currently, your server is behind a firewall which blocks connections from the internet - you want this! If you allowed all traffic from the internet to connect indiscriminately to your server, it would be very vulnerable to attack.

Other applications install and communicate without port-forwarding because the developer provides a server on the internet to act as a proxy between clients. The client connects *out* to the internet which is generally not blocked on home networks. Internal connections going out are considered less harmful than connections coming *in*.

Comment: Maybe more to the point, is there a way to verify the source of a connection before I accept it over a socket? To me this seems impossible but I might as well ask. Also, I do intend to provide public-private key encrypted password login to filter traffic over the port, but I have not gotten there yet.

Comment: ok so I have learned a lot from this question. At this point the biggest thing I think I need to know is this: how do I run my server application from an accessible address, without compromising the security of the network it's on; and without just sacrificing the server's security and placing it outside of the firewall? Should I somehow put it on a separate network?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'verify the source'. You *definitely* cannot verify the source of a connection request before you accept it - you need to accept the connection and then perform authentication as part of whatever protocol you devise. You probably want some form of authentication, either using PKI or some sort of login. I suggest you consider using a prebuilt solution like OpenID Connect using Facebook/Google logins. That might be a bit ambitious in which case a simple login mechanism might be fine to start.
As for the server - why not use port forwarding?

Comment: It's worth noting that you are reinventing the wheel (which some people like to do in order to learn). Depending on what your goal is, you might want to use a bunch of tech to get you forward more quickly. For instance, why not create a Spring Boot web application with web sockets and JSON, secured using HTTPS/WSS and benefitting from all the boilerplate code given to you so you don't have to worry about encryption, authorisation, serialisation etc etc 
You could host it in AWS on the free tier and not have to worry about the firewall stuff.